# Java Corba Different orbs

Tags: java, corba, orb, jacorb

I have currently server and client side in jaCORB it does work fine, however now I want to have the client and server running on different orbs. To be honest I am totally new to corba, I have been looking over the internet but couldn't found something that would help me to undestand this.
I have a idl file in which i specify my methods, then I implement them in my server side implementing Jacorb like that:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass", "org.jacorb.orb.ORB");
    props.put("ORBInitRef.NameService",
            "corbaloc::localhost:8080/NameService");

    org.omg.CORBA.ORB orb = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(args, props);
```

And calling the methods from my client implementing orb like this:

```
            Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass", "org.jacorb.orb.ORB");
        props.put("ORBInitRef.NameService",
                "corbaloc::localhost:8080/NameService");
        MyServer grid;
        org.omg.CORBA_2_3.ORB orb = (org.omg.CORBA_2_3.ORB)org.omg.CORBA_2_3.ORB.init(args, props);
```

And now when I want to have server on different orb, what should I do? Is it only the properties or do I have to change my classes completely? I have spend few hours by now and still doesnt understand my problem, and did not succedded with any code.
Thank you very much for any answers.

Comment: I am not even sure if I go into the right direction, I am trying with org.omg.CORBA.ORB, the erros is can't instantiate default ORB implementation org.omg.CORBA.ORB

Comment: The ORB is an entity from which you have one in each process, it is a local entity, you can't put the ORB within the naming service. You have to create servants which you have to activate in the POA and you can put the client object references for these servants into the naming service. Would recommend you to first look at a hello world example and understand the concepts behind ORB, POA, Servant, and CORBA Object.